# How to Cross Compile Alsa library for Windows Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, cross-compiling

I would like to know how could it be possible to cross compile the Alsa library in Windows for my linux host.

I am using an **iMX8X** with a Linux image, made by Yocto, and I need to implement the Alsa library in my Eclipse to be able to use the functions it gives. I have tried to,

```
CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc(in my case) ./configure host=arm-linux
```

It goes by properly but when I do **make** with **cygwin** it fails and I cannot figure it out.

Anyone know how to approach the cross-compilation of a library for Windows Eclipse?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point on compiling Alsa on Windows, this library works with Linux Core in order to work. There is no actual way, for what I found, to compile it on Windows. Best approach has been to make a Virtual Box machine with Ubuntu 20.04, install Eclipse and compile and add Alsa library in the Ubuntu machine. For more information, just ask me about it, glad to help.